# Getting Type Error during SQL query execution using Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

When I execute the below python code, I get Type error:

```
connsql.cursor().execute(query, name, path,  path, name)
TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

Python Code:

```
connsql,_DATABASE = self.sql_connection()
query = '''
            IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from [%s].[dbo].[config] where name = ? and val = ?)
            BEGIN
                insert into [%s].[dbo].[config] values (?,?)
            END
        ''',(_DATABASE,_DATABASE)
connsql.cursor().execute(query, name, path,  path, name)
connsql.cursor().commit()
connsql.close()
```

Please can anyone help me resolve this error.

Comment: Try `connsql.cursor().execute(query, (name, path,  path, name))`. It's pretty ugly to be chaining cursor creation and execution btw, and I don't think `connsql.cursor().commit()` will even work, because the `commit` is usually executed on the connection, not a cursor

Comment: Also, your string formatting is off; `query` is actually just a tuple

Comment: I am getting same error msg when i change to `Try connsql.cursor().execute(query, (name, path, path, name))`

Comment: Yes, see my second comment. Try `print(query)` and `print(type(query))`